# Cannot install Python Library using conda

Tags: python, conda

I was installing Pandas and matplotlib using 'conda install pandas' and 'conda install matplotlib' but it just hangs after showing Solving environment: done and nothing shows up.
I tried deactivate my Windows Defender but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: pandas and matplotlib are usually included in an Anaconda installation. You do not have to install them.

Comment: if you write `>>>python` and hit enter, and write `>>>import matplotlib`, what happens?

Comment: Or `conda list` at the terminal prompt will show you everything that's already installed